# How to access objects returned by deep dependency in RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Suppose I have three modules, A B and C. C has no dependecies, and B depends on C. Module A depends on module B, so is there a way for A to access C after requiring B?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to by return module C in module B's object.

```
// module C
define([], function() {
   // code
   return { /* c object */ };
});


// module B
define(['c'], function(c) {
   // code
   return { 
      /* b object */,
      'c': c
  }
});

// module A
define(['b'], function(b) {
   // c should now be accessible through b.c;
});
```

Alternatively, module A could require module C and use it. The require optimizer will resolve the dependency for you and only load module C once (for A) and B will still be able to use it.